# Why is there "no such column" in sqlite when `pragma` shows it?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, command-line

I have a table in sqlite, and I can show the columns like so in the sqlite command line:

```
pragma table_info(new_table);
```

and it prints the following:

```
|0|col1,col2,col3,col4|TEXT|0||0
```

then I try to print the column like so:

```
select new_table.col1 from new_table;
Error:no such column:  new_table.col1
```

I tried adding quotes around each column in the csv, but to no avail:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4"
3,4,2,5
5,2,3,6
```

when I try to import this csv ( `.import something.csv new_table`), I get an error:

```
unescaped " character
```

What is the way to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|0|col1,col2,col3,col4|TEXT|0||0` in `pragma table_info` output means that the column name is `col1,col2,col3,col4`. There is no column named `col1`. Check the SQL that created your table - possibly you have e.g. misplaced `""` double quotes around the columns.

---

Edit: To make sqlite3 shell `.import` work with your data, add

```
.separator ","
```

before the `.import`.

Comment: In a CSV, I'm not sure where to add the quotes, though.

Comment: Do you know where I should add the quotes, @laalto  ?

Comment: @Candic3 Edited the answer